# background color does not change

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background color for the icon button in case of iphone screens....
but the color is not changing can you tell how to fix it...
when you reduce the browser window to iphone screen you can see the menu button in grey color....

when i give background-color: red only the border shows red how to show the entire button in red color

http://jsfiddle.net/Zkdfq/

```
.navbar .btn-navbar {
            display: block;
            background-color: red;
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is the:

```
.btn {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #E6E6E6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    ...
}
```

in the bootstrap.css wich declares a background color for your button.
Add a style to your query, like this:

```
.btn {
    background-color: red !important;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar .btn-navbar {
  background: red;
}
```

The gray is a `linear-gradient`, which is like a `background-image`. Use the shorthand to override it.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkdfq/1/)

Comment: thanks for your reply....can you tell me at what line you added the code in the fiddle

Comment: 1495. You could just change your declaration for `background-color`, I just couldn't find it.

Comment: on the hover it shows black color....can u tell how to remove it....